# Navigation Bar Problem while decreasing screen width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width, margin

I am trying to create navbar with image logo, Title, Navigation Links and some social links also. I have created 4 divs for each. Whenever I decrease the screen width using responsive a white color appears in the nav bar and increases to the left as i decrease the screen width.
Here are some pics also:

You can aslo see width on top of the picture
[image]

Here the problem as i decreases the screen width
[image]

```css
/* Reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: PollerOne;
  src: url('../../fonts/Poller_One/PollerOne-Regular.ttf');
}


/* Styling Navigation Bar */

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #262626;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}

.navbar {
  color: white;
  margin: 7px 7px;
}


/* Styling Logo */

#logo {
  background-color: black;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  min-width: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#logo img {
  filter: invert();
  width: 25px;
}


/* Styling Title */

#title {
  font-family: PollerOne;
  min-width: 160.5px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-left: 0px;
}


/* Styling Nav links */

#nav-links {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav-links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  /* padding: 5px 10px; */
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Animation Under Nav Links */

.nav-links::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -4px;
  background: linear-gradient(white 0 0) center/0% 100% no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

:hover.nav-links::after {
  animation: pulse 300ms linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  to {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}


/* Styling Social Links */

#social-links {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.social-links {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.social-links img {
  width: 27px;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.social-links img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5)
}


/* Utility Class */
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="logo" class="navbar">
    <img src="./img/bag.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="title" class="navbar">Meals Point</div>
  <div id="nav-links" class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-links"><a id="link-1">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-links"><a id="link-2">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-links"><a id="link-3">Services</a></li>
      <li class="nav-links"><a id="link-4">Recipes</a></li>
      <li class="nav-links"><a id="link-5">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="social-links" class="navbar">
    <a class="social-links" href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="./img/twitter.png" id="link-1"></a>
    <a class="social-links" href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="./img/facebook.png" id="link-2"></a>
    <a class="social-links" href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="./img/instagram.png" id="link-3"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add to `#navbar` `float: left;` :

```css
/* Reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: PollerOne;
  src: url('../../fonts/Poller_One/PollerOne-Regular.ttf');
}


/* Styling Navigation Bar */

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  height: 65px;
  min-width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#navbar::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #262626;
  height: 65px;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}

.navbar {
  color: white;
  margin: 7px 7px;
}


/* Styling Logo */

#logo {
  background-color: black;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  min-width: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#logo img {
  filter: invert();
  width: 25px;
}


/* Styling Title */

#title {
  font-family: PollerOne;
  min-width: 160.5px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-left: 0px;
}


/* Styling Nav links */

#nav-links {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav-links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  /* padding: 5px 10px; */
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Animation Under Nav Links */

.nav-links::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -4px;
  background: linear-gradient(white 0 0) center/0% 100% no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

:hover.nav-links::after {
  animation: pulse 300ms linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  to {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}


/* Styling Social Links */

#social-links {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.social-links {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.social-links img {
  width: 27px;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.social-links img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5)
}


/* Utility Class */
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="logo" class="navbar">
    <img src="./img/bag.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="title" class="navbar">Meals Point</div>
  <div id="nav-links" class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-links"><a id="link-1">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-links"><a id="link-2">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-links"><a id="link-3">Services</a></li>
      <li class="nav-links"><a id="link-4">Recipes</a></li>
      <li class="nav-links"><a id="link-5">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="social-links" class="navbar">
    <a class="social-links" href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="./img/twitter.png" id="link-1"></a>
    <a class="social-links" href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="./img/facebook.png" id="link-2"></a>
    <a class="social-links" href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="./img/instagram.png" id="link-3"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey is my code is neat and clean i mean understandable for others easily if any improvement just tell i will make

Comment: Hey mate :) if You ask me your code is ok

Comment: Hey Man there is some issue when i scroll down the grey background is fixed to to the top and don't need fixed navbar

Comment: Ahh, sorry mate check now, I updated answer

Answer (score 0):

### Try to add

1. For Left Align:class = "navbar-nav **mr-auto**"
2. For Right Align:class = "navbar-nav **ml-auto**"
3. For Center Align:class = "navbar-nav **mx-auto**"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).